# Стили в Qt применяются не корректно

Tags: c++, qt

Вопрос такой, почему когда прописываю стили в таблице стилей style.qss вот таким способом, то стили не применяются:

```
MyNameSpace--MyWidget                                                               
{ background-image: url(':/MyWidget/background_tooltip.png'); background-position: center center; }
```

А когда прописываю в конструкторе виджета вот так:

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget * parent = nullptr)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MyWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   setStyleSheet("background-image: url(':/MyWidget/background_tooltip.png'); background-position: center center;");
///
}
```

То фон применяется не только к виджету, но и ко всем лейблам и кнопкам внутри этого виджета.

Как это лечить?

Comment: У того виджета object-name совпадает с `MyNameSpace--MyWidget`?

Comment: В qss файле вы не верно задаете виджет. Вместо имени нужно писать QWidget. Также загляните [сюда][1] [1]: http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.5.0/stylesheet-reference.html и [сюда][2] [2]: http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.5.0/stylesheet-syntax.html#style-rules Селектор типов